# .innerHTML not showing up

Tags: javascript, html

I've searched many related stack overflow questions, but can't understand why my `.innerHTML` is not working. I created a javascript file and while `alert` seems to be working fine, the `.innerHTML` doesn't.

```js
function expanddevice(){
  alert('huh?');
  document.getElementbyId("expandservices").innerHTML = "we have great service for iPads";
}
```

```html
<div class="imgDescription">
  <span><a href="#socialmedia">Devices</a></span>
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img onClick="expanddevice()" src="pics/device.png">
  </div>
</div>
<p id="expandservices">Text should appear here:</p>
```

Comment: `getElementById` the case doesn't seem to be correct. check the Console of the Browser, for errors.

Comment: If I can advise you, if you want to debug this kind of code, you should debug first the element returned by your primal function (here for example : alert(document.getElementbyId("expandservices")) just to check where the issue comes from

Comment: the case was the problem, thanks!

Comment: You have an additional `</div>` tag that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @st4rgut Could you please close this question by accepting any answer? As long as you don't this question will be popped back up into the front page now and then which isn't necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo.

try `document.getElementById()`, it is case sensitive.

```
document.getElementById("expandservices").innerHTML = "we have great service for iPads";
```

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitive: `document.getElementById`

Try this

```
function expanddevice(){

    document.getElementById("expandservices").innerHTML = "we have great service for iPads";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Your syntax 
The document.getElementbyid('id') may not be correct may be try the syntax

element = document.getElementById(id);

Answer (score -1):

Try .text or .value because .innerHTML is for divs and spans.

Comment: This is simply not true.